# Integer partition iterative code optimization

Tags: java, optimization, numbers, number-theory, integer-partition

I have been working on code to iteratively partition integers and use previous results to fully partition the numbers, with the idea that using previous partitions can increase speed. So far, I have gotten performance 22x slower than recursively partitioning the integers, and haven't been able to test larger numbers due to quickly running out of memory. If anyone could help optimize the code, I would be grateful for the help.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Summands {
  private static HashMap<Integer, HashSet<List<Integer>>> results;
  private static HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> recursiveResults;

  private static void sort(int[] a) {
    //Radix sort for int array
    int i, m = a[0], exp = 1, n = a.length;
    int[] b = new int[n];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      if (a[i] > m) {
        m = a[i];
      }
    }
    while (m / exp > 0) {
      int[] bucket = new int[n];

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        bucket[(a[i] / exp) % n]++;
      for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1];
      for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        b[--bucket[(a[i] / exp) % n]] = a[i];
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = b[i];
      exp *= n;
    }
  }

  private static void generateResults(int n) {
    //iterative partitioning
    results.put(n, new HashSet<>());
    results.get(n).add(new ArrayList<>());
    for (List<Integer> list : results.get(n)) {
      list.add(n);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= Math.floorDiv(n, 2); i++) {
      //get all 2 summands partitions
      int a = n - i;
      results.get(n).add(Arrays.asList(i, a));
    }
    if (n > 1) {
      //Get the rest of the partitions
      HashSet<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>(results.get(n));
      for (List<Integer> equ : set) {
        if (equ.size() > 1) {
          if (equ.get(1) > 1) {
            HashSet<List<Integer>> temp = results.get(equ.get(1));
            for (List<Integer> k : temp) {
              List<Integer> tempEquList = new ArrayList<>(k);
              tempEquList.add(equ.get(0));
              int[] tempEqu = tempEquList.stream()
                      .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
              sort(tempEqu);
              results.get(n).add(Arrays.stream(tempEqu)
                      .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static void recursivePartition(int n) {
    //recursively partition
    recursiveResults.put(n, new HashSet<>());
    partition(n, n, "", n);
  }

  private static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix, int key) {
    //recursive method for partitioning
    if (n == 0) {
      recursiveResults.get(key).add(prefix);
      return;
    }

    for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
      partition(n - i, i, prefix + " " + i, key);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //get number of partitions to get
    int target = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    //time the iterative version
    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    results = new HashMap<>(target);
    //loop until done
    for (int i = 1; i <= target; i++) {
      System.out.println(i);
      generateResults(i);
    }
    //time both methods
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    recursiveResults = new HashMap<>(target);
    for (int i = 1; i <= target; i++) {
      //loop until done
      System.out.println(i);
      recursivePartition(i);
    }
    long time3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Iterative time: " + String.valueOf(time2 - time1));
    System.out.println("Recursive time: " + String.valueOf(time3 - time2));
    /*for (Integer key : results.keySet()) {
      //For ensuring proper amount of partitions
      //for lower numbers. Primarily for testing
      System.out.println(key + ": " + results.get(key).size());
    }*/
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide some context.  What do you mean by "integer partition"?  Show examples of input and output.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you aren't using the explicit formula given in the wikipedia article? It seems like a simple job for memoisation, not the insanely complicated thing that you've built. Note: since your code seems to be working - if slowly - you may have more luck posting this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are bound to be people who will happily optimise your code as is, but if you're lucky then some people may look at the fundamentals (math/algorithmics). Just don't expect anyone to analyse this convoluted mess without a modicum of explanation.

Comment: If you add the C++ tag to your question I will post an optimized solution for you

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a set of combinations of the summands of the specified number, i.e. *the integer partition*, using `mapToObj` and `reduce` methods. First prepare the *sets of arrays* of summands, and then multiply the pairs of these *sets* sequentially and get the *Cartesian product*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVZNb9swDL3nV/Aob6279jIgaQIMxQ47FDukt6IHxaZTpbakSXSLoMhvzyjZcdLmw@2A6ZLoi3yPj6S8kM/yfJE/rdeqssYRLHghrUmV6ZfRYG/Nk0NZha2BrWelyiArpfdwK5WG1wHwaNc9SeKfZ6NyqHhXTMkpPb9/AOnmPmkPh6E0gYYxfB91S1Oka16@f5iAlY4UKRNO/NI0bQA4qecovp2BTrpLm3FxAdYh30PwSB5MwS6dXMZ/vq4qqXO/dyutpL0zv2cLoeB88t7VTWk85uKSHcI5qH2n@2YWwYzGF4hEXher45cYcePs@s4hbslPjrvJTFliRuKm@TXOp2TaCQdLHL254zMzFUeJRQF6RJ5pQt3Ei15MG7NeOyLZ8Nxgn4gf8epw2DjAhMchlZgkugpzJQnB1GRrOvuUZBbxSfCFgGC69IRVymZSy5yoPBEDvtJmskiCYB1gMk2WJofiuzBK8544Rsfjn5oDqGTZQI5Jy/itVK4hEqjVFsjEgM/VM2rQdTVDt8/NYV5nKAK9yxiVqxjoMO2wD06LO1M6gojOldbo@kRNi1LSLQeEz10Gd6@DnhxipjFhmA@WWHUJxPOCaVPj8aSVUP/BzBgaGTb0AoYk5R2RjPpgqMalt5ipQmHehhWUB7aVPWJ@GkIBIkIYc0PhG1Q7/Q5NV8lcywHZqh@UYUjuRfmmtpSuEaS1qPNQckezene0SIL6nejBcu6MbYt2R2V6lCHenFl8kg4k1WHJVclnQ7SvguJ7Gly1GsDXqNL1@FDPPdYKO7NtMzVFlPUMouEPmXmfm3eGe3NXsQ3OT1ry/KhxN0@4ZUY7XNKjENaYQnGvJ21XSVPw9LZT7arx7607IukacKNqroriA4KGpNPlkhMVjMtjvcfk84onzCoSlBVuX9X/2d@3@S81YGVp@TZk@03PuJ@lR9HjjT8@drwUHPGyez4Cw/CuzJn89tPBHG4PnZnuZN@zUDBCbidi@9oMh@1z0/aD1WC1Xv8F)

```java
int n = 7;
Set<int[]> partition = IntStream.range(0, n)
        // prepare sets of arrays of summands
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n - i)
            .mapToObj(j -> new int[]{j})
            // Stream<TreeSet<int[]>>
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
                // comparing the contents of two arrays
                () -> new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare))))
        // intermediate output, sets of arrays of summands
        .peek(set -> System.out.println(
            set.stream().map(Arrays::toString).collect(Collectors.joining())))
        // sequential summation of pairs of sets up to the given number
        .reduce((set1, set2) -> set1.stream()
            // combinations of inner arrays
            .flatMap(arr1 -> {
                // sum of the elements of the first array
                int sum = Arrays.stream(arr1).sum();
                // if the specified number is reached
                if (sum == n) return Arrays.stream(new int[][]{arr1});
                // otherwise continue appending summands
                return set2.stream() // drop the combinations that are greater
                    .filter(arr2 -> Arrays.stream(arr2).sum() + sum <= n)
                    .map(arr2 -> Stream.of(arr1, arr2)
                        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                        .sorted().toArray()); // the sorted array
            }) // set of arrays of combinations
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection( // two arrays that differ
                // only in order are considered the same partition
                () -> new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare))))
        // otherwise an empty set of arrays
        .orElse(new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare));
```

```java
// final output, the integer partition of the specified number
partition.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Intermediate output, sets of arrays of summands:

```
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]
[1][2][3][4][5][6]
[1][2][3][4][5]
[1][2][3][4]
[1][2][3]
[1][2]
[1]
```

Final output, the integer partition of the specified number:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 5]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 6]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 5]
[3, 4]
[7]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Building permutation that sums to a number efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67306387/15766209)</sup>